# Using the Ready an Action to use Swallow Whole

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, readied-action

Could I ready an action to use Swallow Whole?

Answer (score 8):

### Swallow Whole is not something you can ready

> If a creature with this special attack **begins its turn** with an
>   opponent grappled in its mouth (see Grab), it can attempt a new combat
>   manoeuver check (as though attempting to pin the opponent). If it
>   succeeds, it swallows its prey, and the opponent take bites damages

(emphasis mine)

You can ready a bite attack, but *Swallow Whole* is an ability that specifically triggers at the start of one turn. Note that it goes the same way for an eidolon or a monster, or any creature with the standard *Swallow Whole* special ability.